# Not getting last updated id while running code from php. If the query run in phpmyadmin it will return the last updated id

Tags: php, mysql

Not getting last updated id while running code from PHP. If the query runs in PHPMyAdmin it will return the last updated id

```
SET @LastUpdateID := 0;
UPDATE ibe_session_pool t1 JOIN
(
SELECT t2.id FROM ibe_session_pool t2
WHERE t2.query_in_progress='0' LIMIT 0,1
)dummy
ON t1.id=dummy.id
SET t1.sequence_number = (CASE  
WHEN t1.sequence_number < 999 THEN t1.sequence_number+1
ELSE 1
END),
t1.id = (SELECT @LastUpdateID := t1.id),
t1.query_in_progress='1';
SELECT @LastUpdateID AS LastUpdateID;
```

---

```
$afftectedRows =  $this->db->query($queryUpdate);
```

Comment: maybe you got a problem in your PHP code?

Comment: The update process done successfully in php code. But not get last updated id